# error installing openmeeting local system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openmeetings

I am installing openmeeting 3.0.1 in local machine. While installing i am facing following error. How to solve this issue?

```
WARN 05-30 16:29:27.879 o.a.o.d.d.b.ConfigurationDao:123      [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-6] - Could not find key     in configuration CONF_KEY: mail.smtp.timeout
DEBUG 05-30 16:29:27.879 o.a.o.q.s.TestSetupCleanupJob:34 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-5] -  TestSetupClearJob.execute
DEBUG 05-30 16:29:27.880 o.a.o.m.MailHandler:258 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-6] - sendMails enter ...
DEBUG 05-30 16:29:28.114 o.a.o.m.MailHandler:260 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-6] - Number of emails in init queue 0
DEBUG 05-30 16:29:28.114 o.a.o.m.MailHandler:265 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-6] - ... sendMails done.
DEBUG 05-30 16:29:32.832 o.a.o.d.d.s.SessiondataDao:404 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-7] - ****** clearSessionTable:
```

Comment: Dependency problem was there. Now i have installed everything properly.

Comment: Hey, I have exactly the same problem, could you be so kind and explain in more detail what the problem was and how to resolve the dependency issue? Thanks

Comment: @medonja: Follow each installation steps provided in this link. Finally run sh red5.sh. It will work. http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2013/03/14/installing-openmeeting-with-mysql

Comment: @medonja: if you get success don't forget to upvote :)

Comment: I have followed the instructions, got finally my db tables created, but I am still getting the "Could not find key in configuration CONF_KEY: number.minutes.reminder.send" loop (along with some other lines). I'm trying to install OpenMeetings 3.0.1, maybe there's another dependency needed with this version of OpenMeetings?

Comment: first run these commands: sh admin.sh, then try sh red5.sh and in browser open http://localhost:5080/openmeetings/install.

Comment: Actually, I simply overlooked that I need to shut down my firewall... after turning it off it worked like a charm. I still need to review the firewall configuration though ;)

Answer (score -2):

Though I see you already found a solution one may also wish to try the following:
1. Go to the releases page: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/releases
2. Download tarball: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/releases/download/v1.0.5-RELEASE/red5-server-1.0.5-RELEASE-server.tar.gz (or you can use *.zip)
3. Extract it somewhere
4. Run `red5.sh` (`red5.bat`)

Also, installing sendmail as part of your prerequisite can also help with  SNMP Key errors